# Automatic Reference counting in Objective-C

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

I want to know if ARC is enabled in iPhone Project while I am working in Xcode solution . How much do I need to know about Memory management like do I still need to understand the life cycle of objects and release them from memory myself.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to understand the life cycle of objects.  You do not need to send `release` messages yourself.  If you have a variable that references an object, and you no longer need to keep the object alive, set the variable to `nil`.  Under ARC, that is all you need to do to renounce ownership of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer david but i did not understood it completely can you please give me an simplest of an example please

Comment: @user2332873 who's David. Rob is the one who answered your question.